# Query table by id and choose default if not present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

[image]

I want to retrieve all the rows that match a specific ProductId and ReportType. Now here is the kicker. Not all ProductIds exist for all ReportType/TextBockType combinations. But, there is always a value with with a ProductId of 0. A ProductId of 0 represents the **default** value.

In other words: If a row with a specific ProductId/ReportType/TextBlockType does not exist, I want to return the row with the ReportType/TextBlockType combination for ProductId 0.

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

What an awesome question!  Let's say you're looking for ProductID = 20 And ReportType = 35 And TextBlockType = 102.  If ProductID = 20 doesn't exist and you would accept the default of 0 then this mockup might help:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
  ProductID int,
  ReportType int,
  TextBlockType int,
  TextBlock nvarchar(MAX)
)

INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (10,15,100,'abc')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,15,100,'cba')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,25,102,'abc')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,25,102,'abc')
-- Comment | Uncomment to test receipt of record with ProductID = 20 or ProductID = 0
--INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (20,35,102,'def')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,35,102,'def')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,35,102,'ghi')
INSERT @MyTable (ProductID, ReportType, TextBlockType, TextBlock) VALUES (0,35,102,'jkl')

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReportType, TextBlockType  ORDER BY ProductID     DESC) AS rownumber
   FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE rownumber = 1 and (ProductID = 20 or ProductID = 0)  And ReportType = 35 And TextBlockType = 102
```